# Remove duplicated div style tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to clean up my code. I would like to remove duplicated -tags

An example:

```
var testString = '<div style="text-align: right;">text1</div><div style="text-align: right;">text2</div>', str;

str = testString.replace(/<div style="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/div><div style="$1">/g, '<div style="$1">$2<br>');
```

In my head str should now contain `'<div style="text-align: right;">text1<br>text2</div>'`.

I know i am wrong, but where?

Hope you guys understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a different style for the backreference variable, `\1` instead of `$1` in the regex.
Try this:

```
str = testString.replace(/<div style="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/div><div style="\1">/g, '<div style="$1">$2<br>');
```

Comment: Can you perhaps help me out with the extended problem - 
What if there is multiple `<div style="text-align: right;">`?

So `<div style="text-align: right;">text1</div><div style="text-align: right;">text2</div><div style="text-align: right;">text3</div>` will be cleaner...

Comment: This may be possible with a callback function, but I am not such a JavaScript expert. The better option may be in this case to use a xml/html parser.

Comment: @MortenHauberg please mark this answer as accepted and start a new question. This is the better option to recieve good answers.